# Image NOT displaying in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am facing an issue while displaying an image from `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`.
I am able to save an image and store it in `LocalFolder`, but displaying it in a `Image` control or `LongListSelector`, the image does not show up.

Here is the code:

```
private async void StoreToFile(string imageFileName)
{
   StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(imageFileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
   using (Stream current = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
   {
      await photoStream.CopyToAsync(current);
   }
}
```

Here is the code to bind:

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var images = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
Recent.ItemsSource = images.ToList();
```

XAML Code:

```
<phone:PivotItem Name="pivot1" Header="item2" Background="White">
   <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Recent" Margin="0,0,0,72" ItemsSource="{Binding lst}" >
      <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
               <Image  Source="{Binding Path}" Width="60"/>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
   </phone:LongListSelector>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

I am able to bind the path to a `TextBlock` and able to see the exact path like:

> C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData{GUID}\Local\bucket.png

But if I bind to an image source, images are not displaying.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot bind to such paths, you must load images yourself from the stream and create bitmaps for binding to `Image.Source`.

Comment: Appreciate if you can give a small working example

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the msappx uri scheme:

```
new Uri("ms-appx:///myimage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

As ToniPetrina has said in comment - you can't bind to Path, your property should return BitmapImage. There are two approaches that come to my mind:

- provide a special getter of your property that will return BitmapImage (some code below)
- provide a Converter when binding to IsolatedStorage image - [here is very nice example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608833/BindingplustoplusImageplusPathplusinplusIsolatedpl)

The sample code for the first solution can look like this:
In Xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="myList" Grid.Row="2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
             <Image Source="{Binding GetImgSource}" Width="60"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In code behind:

```
public class Images : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private string imgSource = "";
   public string SetImgSource // setter - string
   {
      set
      {
        imgSource = value;
        RaiseProperty("GetImgSource");
      }
   }
   public BitmapImage GetImgSource // getter - BitmapImage
   {
     get
     {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(imgSource)) return null;
        BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage();

        using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
          using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = ISF.OpenFile(imgSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
              temp.SetSource(file);

        return temp;
     }
  }

  public void RaiseProperty(string property = null)
  {
      if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
          this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
  }
}

ObservableCollection<Images> myImg = new ObservableCollection<Images>();

myList.ItemsSource = myImg; // somewhere
```

Comment: Thanks Romasz. I am getting the count as 0 for myImg. ObservableCollection<Images> myImg = new ObservableCollection<Images>();

myList.ItemsSource = myImg; // somewhere

Comment: Added myImg.Add(new Images() { SetImgSource = ImagePath }); Still no luck. No Images are displaying

Comment: @user3266804 myList.ItemsSource for example in contructor of the Page. Have you tried adding myImg.Add(new Images() {"bucket.png"}); ? Have you checked that you image exists?

Comment: Yes... I declared globally ObservableCollection<Images> myImg = new ObservableCollection<Images>(); and in constructor myList.ItemsSource = myImg; myImg.Add(new Images() { SetImgSource = Path.Combine(localFolderPath, filename) }); I checked the image exists by using ISETool.

Comment: @user3266804 Can you check it wihout this localpath and so on. Just myImg.Add(new Images() { SetImgSource = "bucket.png"}); - it refers to your IsolatedStorage so its relative. As I've checked it should work.

Comment: I tried with only name... Still no luck. below method am using to get the filenames.   private void TempFile()
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                string[] fn = ISF.GetFileNames();
                myImg.Add(new Images() { SetImgSource = fn[0] });
            }
        }. Note: fn[0] is "1_neeraj.png"

Comment: @user3266804 Nah - then test this example: http://sdrv.ms/1brlc8I Check the difference with your code - in constructor I copy images from resources to IsolatedStorage, then I use them. First click adds image to list. Tell me what you had wrong.

Comment: Romasz, Thanks for your code. Your code works perfectly when the image copied from different source (web). But when i capture image from Camera and update your code. Its not binding to the ListBox\LongListSelector. Atlast what I did is manually adding the images one by one. like lstImages.Items.Add(img1) and it works

Comment: @user3266804 Are you using Images taken by Camera? Are they copied to IsolatedStorage? (the above code works with files on IsolatedStorage).

Comment: Images taken from Windows Phone camera and stored in IsolatedStorate